# How to export Knowledge articles

Tags: articles

Is there a way to export knowledge articles from sandbox and import it to production environment ?

I tried translation workbench but it is not working. My articles contain images, so i cannot use dataloader.

How to do this ? Any suggestion  Please ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The steps to on how to export  knowledge aticles are documented below

https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=knowledge_translation_export.htm&language=en

To generate an export file containing the articles that have been submitted for translation:

1. From Setup, click Data Management | Export Articles for Translation.
2. Select the queue that contains the articles you're exporting.

3)Click either:

```
    1)All articles to export every article in the queue. 
    2)Updated articles to only export articles that have been modified or added.
```

1. Click Continue.
2. Select the source and target language pairs you want to export.
       Salesforce creates a separate .zip file for every article type in
       each language pair.

Answer (score -3):

Export articles:
Knowledge articles can be exported from Salesforce as a package zip file which includes property file, csv, and folder of html files including attachments from production using an Salesforce third party app “Heroku”. This procedure doesn’t need any installation. By providing Salesforce login credentials, we can download articles based on below filters.

•   Publication Status:
   Online
   Draft
   Archived
•   Language

Maximum of 500 articles can be exported at a time from Salesforce Heroku. User with Sys Admin, CCBIC profiles can export articles from Salesforce.

Why Heroku:
Salesforce does not have any inbuild setup to export/transfer files from one sandbox to another. Salesforce provides export options only for translations, within the same org.

Step-By-Step Procedure:
1.  Log in Salesforce Production Org.
2.  Hit the Heroku export article Link https://kbapps2.herokuapp.com/exportk2k/
3.  Choose Production and provide salesforce login credentials
4.  Export articles based on the filter provided by the app.
5.  Export in Salesforce Article importer format
6.  Once done, mail will be sent to the exported user. Download from the mail.

Please find below reference screenshot of Heroku app.

Import articles:
Salesforce itself provides a setup to import articles.
Salesforce pre-requisites:
•   Enable/Check the Knowledge user checkbox for the required user.
•   Ensure read/edit/create article permission for the profile.
•    Ensure import article wizard is enabled for the users.

Step-By-Step Procedure:
1.  Enable/Check the Knowledge user checkbox for the required user.
2.  Ensure Read/Create/Edit permission is enabled for the profile.
3.  Ensure Article type and data category are identical in both the orgs.
4.  Rename the importing zip file as language code(en__US/ru) and ensure the zip file contains Property file, CSV and folder of html files.
5.  In salesforce setup, Search and open Import article wizard.
6.  In import article wizard, select the type of article and upload the updated zip file.
7.  Click import 
8.  Imported status and log can be viewed in import/export article log.
9.  The imported articles will be listed as draft files under knowledge draft folder.

Knowledge articles types and data category types can be exported through ant script and deployed to the required org.
The knowledge layout is translated based on the user’s local language.

Comment: This looks to be copied from a help page, but you haven't cited the source. If true, you have just plagiarized someone else's work (that's a bad thing). Please read [answer].

Comment: Please do cite any sources and mark quotes as such in your post. Please also use the formatting tools available in the editor to ensure it renders correctly.