# Bulk archive knowledge Articles in salesforce

Tags: articles, lightning-knowledge

How to archive bulk knowledge articles. I have list of articles 950 provided by business team.Can any one please help me on this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to export Knowledge articles](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/45855/how-to-export-knowledge-articles)

Comment: Welcome to SFSE.  Please take a moment to read [ask] and take the [tour].